# Жирный шрифт в блоках кода

Tags: поддержка, форматирование

```
Как сделать в таком блоке **жирный** <b>шрифт</b>?
```

```html
Проверка через <b>HTML</b> код.
```

Comment: Пишите более развернутые и понятные другим вопросы.

Comment: Никак.‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏

Comment: @Squidward `<pre>
Тут будет <b>жирный шрифт</b>

</pre>` не в счет? или я не понял вопрос?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вечно забываю, что MD включает HTML. Правда тогда подсветка синтаксиса отваливается. Пишите ответ. :)

Comment: @TonyTov, очевидно в комментариях это не работает

Comment: @TonyTov В комментариях синтаксис сильно ограничен.

Comment: Как можно иначе выделить часть кода в вопросе? ( кнопка {} - pre code Ctrl+K )

Comment: Прошу прощения. А инструкции по этому поводу гдето существуют? если да, то где? Если нет, то давайте напишем=)

Comment: @Squidward, подсветка работает, но не всегда))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ты `<code>` забыл.

Comment: @LexHobbit я вот не хочу, чтобы участники начали выделять код полужирным, курсивом, цветом и так далее. Код хорош в стандартном форматировании с подсветкой синтаксиса. Так что не надо инструкцию )

Comment: @Qwertiy а зачем `<code>`?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский См. ответ @Qwertiy, который я проапгрейдил. `<code>` семантически — для кода, функционально — для включения подсветки.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin♦ Да я не про код, а про обычный даже текст, типа underline, strike и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: @LexHobbit а, так есть такая инструкция. Откройте редактирование вопроса, там ссылка.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ну да, видел ее, например мне просто не пришло в голоову кликнуть по [ссылке](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed). А сейчас перешел и она на английском. Не то чтобы у меня с английским большие проблемы, но мы всеже "SO на русском"

Comment: @LexHobbit я про эту: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @NickVolynkin и я про нее, как раз с которой можно перейти на указанную выше мной ссылку. В разделе про HTML "большинство опасных тегов отключено!"

Answer (score 6):

### Текст без форматирования кода

```html
<pre>В этом блоке <b>жирный</b> шрифт. Вот.</pre>
```

```
В этом блоке жирный шрифт. Вот.
```

### Текст с форматированием кода

```html
<!-- language: lang-php -->
<pre><code>function foo ($foo) { <i>foo</i>(); /* foo <b>bar</b> baz */ }</code></pre>
```

```php
function foo ($foo) { foo(); /* foo bar baz */ }
```

Comment: О, сработало.‎‏